# Omit in for loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a function to move between the given range of values, but I would like to add in my function a parameter that will be an array which would contain the numbers which must be skipped while my function run iteration

my function:

```
    nums = []

    def loopIteration(minValue, maxValue):
        minValue += 1
        for i in range(maxValue-minValue+1):
            num = i+minValue
            nums.append(Num('numbers_{}'.format(i)))

#function call
loopIteration(4,25)
```

i want to add in my function call an parameter like this:

```
loopIteration(4,25,[8,9,16])
```

thanks for any answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Continue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) is a Python syntax which would allow you to pass iteration in a for loop. Usually, continue can make it quite hard to follow flow later on, if you ever wish to look back on your script. Here is what you could do:

```
def loopInteration(minValue, maxValue, skipNums):
   for number in range(maxValue-minValue+1):
       if number in skipNums:
           continue
       num = i+minValue
       nums.append(Num("numbers_{}".format(i)))

loopIteration(4,25,[NUMBERS HERE])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `continue` to skip certain `i`s:

```
def loopIteration(minValue, maxValue, skip=set()):
    for i in range(minValue + 1, maxValue + 1):
        if i in skip:
            continue
        cells.append(Cell("numbers_{}".format(i)))
```

Comment: how you can call this function?

Comment: Exactly as in your example: `loopIteration(4,25,[8,9,16])`